# Tab links on recent activity page don't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, navigation

On the Recent Activity page (accessible by clicking the envelope icon next to the user's name at the top) (eg. https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/recent/34 ), clicking on the tabs (Summary, Reputation, Responses etc) causes a blank page to appear (400 Bad Request).

This may have to do with the url - on SO the url is of the format https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/1943?startdate=2010-08-24%2015%3a32%3a27z&enddate=2010-08-24%2023%3a59%3a59z&tab=summary#tab-top

while on ui, it's https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/recent/34/2010-08-24%2014:41:53z/2010-08-24%2023:59:59z?tab=reputation#tab-top ('/' instead of '?' after userid)

Comment: Possibly related bug: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/899/10k-tools-are-broken-tag-instead-of-tab

Comment: ok I changed this stuff in 30 places yesterday... looks like I messed one up, will fix asap

Comment: Can someone remove the 'status-completed' tag? It's still not fixed.

Comment: @George Edison @waffles - what site is it not fixed on still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the latest deployed revision: 2010.8.24.1. I can replicate it on SuperUser and I think it is linked to the bug I reported [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1314/10k-tools-page-broken-on-superuser).

I have reported the latter to [Marc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) already, and I am pretty sure it will be resolved ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

I had to rip out an internal dependency that in turn meant I rewrote all the Tab helper function.

Long story short, my bug, fixed now.

Comment: Possibly broken again?

Comment: @Tim: Yup... it's not working for me.

Comment: @Tim, @George and not working here either.

Comment: @waffles. Still not working on rev: 2010.8.24.5. Which one should have the fix?

Comment: @Diago: failing for me on SO rev. 2010.8.24.1.

Comment: @Richard. That would be correct since that's the version that originally caused the problem.

Comment: @Diago @Richard ... all is deployed now ... and there is a new magic feature there ... any feedback on it (hint click on a tag)

Comment: @waffles. Awesome!

Comment: @Waffles: Thanks, seems good now.