# Did the 10k tools page on SO change recently? It has stopped working for me

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab links on recent activity page don’t work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62148/tab-links-on-recent-activity-page-dont-work)

In the last few minutes I have lost the ability to change tabs (it's stuck on "stats") on the 10k tools page. Tried clearing my caches and restarting the browser, but no dice.

I'm also stuck on meta.

Firefox 3.6, Mac OS X 10.5. Also tried with Safari and the problem persists.

Are other affected? Has something changed?

Possibly related to [10K Tools Page Broken on SuperUser](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1314/10k-tools-page-broken-on-superuser).

Comment: This is the same bug as reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62148/tab-links-on-recent-activity-page-dont-work-on-ui-stackexchange-com)

Comment: @Larry, might be, but if so they didn't fix it for the 10k tools page.

Comment: My fault, I have it fixed in dev, will be deployed in a few hours

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @waffles: did your recent changes have anything to do with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62205/invalid-url-when-using-many-tags-2010-8-25-1-on-so? (ie, some side-effects might explain why some url doesn't work today)